# Running into a hang in SWIG generated code at SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017, swig

I have a C# DLL which calls methods generated via SWIG that translate into calls into my C++ DLL (Native). In Release mode it seems to work, however in debug it hangs at SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_%Module. I've tried everything I can think of to figure what the problem is but SWIG is very opaque and stepping into it does not help any.

I'm using the latest version of swig. I would post my code but the solution I'm working with possesses more than a million lines of code.

I've run Dependency Walker to figure out if there's some dependency dll missing. It does complain that the C++ DLL was not found. However, the DLL is in that directory. All the C++ DLLs have been retargeted to 10.0.17763.0 and all the C# is based on .NET Framework 4.7.2.

I can't figure out how to move forward. Anybody have any good advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Is your .dll added to the project via the 'References'? Or are you just dropping it in the /bin/ folder. I would add it as a reference if not.

Comment: The dll is copied during the build where all of the others are copied to along with the executables. So they are all in the same directory. That the weird part, the solution builds everything and then copies it all to the same output directory. The DLL that it complains about is there but the swig code for unknown reasons doesn't see it